# Mapping attributes using @JsonProperty when binding play.data.Form from JsonNode

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

I have the following class

```
public static class Thing {
    @JsonProperty("_name_")
    String name;
}
```

and I'm trying to bind it to the form and get instance of this class this way

```
ObjectNode node = Json.newObject();
node.put("_name_", "some name");

Form<Thing> thingForm = Form.form(Thing.class);
thingForm = thingForm.bind(node);
Thing thing = thingForm.get();
```

So, I expect that `thing.name` will be "some name" but it's not, it is `null`. I understant that `@JsonProperty` is for Json (de)serialization, just tried if it works. The question is how to achieve this with Play's Form?

I also tried to [Register a custom DataBinder](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms) as described in docs, but its methods never gets called.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `thingForm.bindFromRequest()` instead of `thingForm.bind()`? I am using exactly same thing where I make an ajax post with json data and it is working fine for me. It doesn't look like it has anything to do with @JsonProperty().

Are you sure if you want to have class Thing `static` ? I am assuming you have public getter/setters for your form properties.